# View Results in Table Listener not capturing BeanShell Failure/Success

Tags: jmeter, jmeter-plugins

I have 3 assertions implemented, but `View Results in Table Listener` is showing only 1st assertion failure in CSV output.

[image]

Listener shows 3 failures though.

[image]

This is how Bean Shell Assertion looks

```
String var1 = vars.get("source");
String var2 = vars.get("target");

Failure = !var1.equals(var2);

if (Failure) {
  FailureMessage = "Variables are not equal. Expected \"" + var1 + "\" , actual:\"" + var2 + "\"";
} else {
    PassMessage = "Variables are equal. Expected \"" + var1 + "\" , actual:\"" + var2 + "\"";
}
```

Also, it doesn't show Pass Message in CSV output of `View Results in Table Listener`

Answer (score 0):

1. There is no such a shorthand as `PassMessage`, there is `ResponseMessage` which you can use to modify the `responseMessage` column value for the given Sampler
2. 2nd, 3rd, whatever assertions should be executed unless there are no syntactical errors there, look at [jmeter.log file](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#logging) for any suspicious entries
3. [Since JMeter 3.1 you're supposed to be using JSR223 Test Elements and Groovy language](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/best-practices.html#bsh_scripting) for scripting so it might be a better idea to consider switching to [JSR223 Assertion](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/scripting-jmeter-assertions-in-groovy-a-tutorial/)
4. In general it's recommended to use built-in test elements and avoid scripting where possible, if all you need to do is to compare 2 variables it can be done using "normal" [Response Assertion](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Response_Assertion)

   [image]

Comment: #4 it worked, it doesn't require scripting. But, where can I configure `Success Message`? I am able to configure the failure message below Pattern to Test field, but not the success message.

Comment: I found a way to show success message, but main question is still there. There are 3 assertions, if all are failing then all should be captured in CSV of `View Results in Table Listener` (pic 1 in the question) but it shows the first failure